# How to make TabBarController inside another TabBarController in swift storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nested, uitabbarcontroller

I wanna know how to create nested `UITabBarControllers` in Xcode, I'm using Swift.

My first `UITabBarController` has two items: Search (`UITableView`) and Map (`MKMapView`).
When I hit a cell in my table I wanna go to the second `UITabBarController`.
This second `UITabBarController` is the detail page for the clicked cell and must have three items --> Info, Reviews and Contact.

Can anyone explain how to do this? Right now I only have the first `UITabBarController` and a single view controller for the detail page working.

EDIT: The main problem is that when I nest the `UITabBarControllers`, my app always shows the items of the first `UITabBarController`.

Comment: What problem are you having? Just add it like any other view controller.

Comment: I would argue you to follow Apple's suggestion to *"use [tab bar controllers] only in these specific ways:

Install it directly as a window’s root view controller.

Install it as one of the two view controllers in a split view interface. (iPad only)

Present it modally from another view controller.

Display it from a popover. (iPad only)"* You can find that recommendation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

Just create a segue between the list view and the second tab controller. 
And select on the second tab controller `hide bottom bar on push` in the attributes inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Make another Tab View Controller next to it (You should see two tab view controllers on the storyboard), and then inside the Tab View Controller you want the other one in, insert a Container View. After the Container View is in the desired Tab View Controller and sized properly, hold control and drag from the Container View to the other Tab View Controller. After releasing, select embed and you should be good to go! Hope this helps. If it does, please vote this up :)

Comment: I see that you found the solution. Awesome to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop new `tabbarcontroller` from stroryboard and from your list view controller ctrl+drag to this newtabbar controller and select `show segue`. (assuming that you are using navigation controller)

Comment: i can only choose for push, modal or custom